# Magento2: Where in admin product review can be managed

Tags: magento2, review

In Magento2.0 admin side, where we can manage the product reviews.

I got some spam reviews which I want to delete them but cant able to find a place at admin side to manage the reviews.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can manage review at: `MARKETING > User Content > Reviews`

Answer (score 2):

In UI Magento ver. 2.1.x

`MARKETING > User Content > Reviews`

[image: saurabh ranjan]

Manage all reviews

[image: inrsaurabh]